# Java - Object properties does not differ

Tags: java

```
ClassName ref = new ClassName();
ref.setCredentials(Credentials);
ref.setVal(value);
ref.setUser(user);
```

Now when I create a new object of the same class reference, I still get the previous values I have set. Why is this so?

```
ClassName ref2 = new ClassName();
ref2.setVal(value);
ref2.setUser(user);
ref2.setSomethingNew(somethingNew);
```

My `ref` and `ref2` instances have all the values [`Credentials, Value, User and SomethingNew`]. I want to differentiate these two instances. Is it because it's holding the same object?

**Update My Lapse:**

It's actually `ref2` and not `ref`. I get the values in `ref2` which i am not setting, and `ref` too holds a value which I am setting in the instance of `ref2`. Both are in same context.

Comment: you did `ref.setVal(...)` instead of `ref2.setVal(...)`.

Comment: `ref.equals(ref2)` ... what does it result?

Comment: I don't know why you use same value in both objects. The only way to detect objects are not equal is check based on `Reference equality` i.e. Check `ref2==ref`

Comment: @AmitD `ref2==ref` is what `Object.equals` is using that I already suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that with `ref2` you are only creating the object, but you are setting the values to `ref`. You need:

```
ClassName ref2 = new ClassName();
ref2.setVal(value);
ref2.setUser(user);
ref2.setSomethingNew(somethingNew);
```

Note the `ref2` change instead of `ref`.

If your `ClassName` is overriding the `equals` method, and all the inner objects are equal also, it is normal to have equality between `ref` and `ref2`. You can use `Object.equals` implementation to detect if the objects are different (note `different` vs. `equal`).

Comment: @AmitD Can you provide more details? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @dan Edit was not detected by `SO` it took a while I guess to detect the edit.

Comment: @AmitD Yes, it happened to me also, with OP's update. Something is slow today.

Answer (score 3):

If you set on `ref` even after creating `ref2` this is what you should expect. Do this:

```
ref2.setVal(value);
```

**Note:** Don't do this:

```
ref.setCredentials(Credentials);
```

It sets the *class*  `Credentials` on `ref`.