# object properties are not the same

Tags: java

This is an update of the same question, which is partly solved.

[Java - Object properties does not differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192965/java-object-properties-does-not-differ)

```
int size = 0;
int new = 10;
int default = 100;

ClassList filterList = new ClassList();
filterList.setSize(size);
filterList.setNew(new);
filterList.setDefault(default);
```

// Now i am creating another instance of the ClassList.

```
ClassList newList = ClassList();
```

Its strange that my newList has values of `size, new and default`, but with values as `0, 0 and 0` I tried to check whether the instances are same or not.

```
if(filterList .equals(newList)){
    Log.d("Is it equal","True");
    } else {
    Log.d("Its Not equal","false");
}
```

**I got it false.**

My POJO class is plain simple with getters and setters.

```
public class ClassList{

    private int size;
    private int new;
    private int default;

    public int getPageSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setPageSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Comment: since when can `new` and `default` be used as field names?

Comment: your code wouldnt even compile... you are using new and default as variable names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value for `int` is `0` that is why `size, new and default` has values `0, 0 and 0` on newly created instance

Default equals comparison happens on `==` that is reference equality.
You will need to override `equals` and `hashcode`

From Java doc of [Object#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

**Sample Implementaion :**

```
public static class ClassList {

    private int size;
    private int newValue;
    private int defaultValue;

    public int getPageSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setPageSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ClassList))
            return false;
        ClassList c = (ClassList) obj;

        return this.size == c.size && this.newValue == c.newValue
                && this.defaultValue == c.defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.valueOf(size).hashCode()
                + Integer.valueOf(newValue).hashCode()
                + Integer.valueOf(defaultValue).hashCode();
    }
}
```

*Note: `new` and `default` are reserved keywords in java. You can not define variable names for reserve keywords.*

---

References:

- [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`hashcode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
- [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: Can you show me out on how would i call the equals method in my other class and print out the results in log. thanks

Comment: Default value for `int` is 0 that is why you have values of `size, new and default`. The way you are calling equals is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override  `equals` and `hashcode` method for custom equaling.

```
public class ClassList{

    private int size;
    private int new;
    private int default;

    public int getPageSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setPageSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
         if (obj == null)
             return false;
         else if (obj == this)
             return true;
         else if (obj.getClass() != getClass())
             return false;
         else
             return this.hashCode()==obj.hashCode();
    }
    public int hashCode(){
       return size+new+default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the **equals** and **hashCode** methods in your ClassList class.

You can do this with Eclipse by right clicking in the java file -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals().

Answer (score 1):

Object equality in Java is not determined by the state fo the object's fields per default - each instance is different from any other.

You will have to override the `equals` method to make it return `true` depending on the object state.

Implementing `equals` correctly might not be as straightfoward. Look up the 
[API docs for the equals method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for implementation advice.